# How to transform categorical variable to its frequency.

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

For example, my df is {'a','a','a','b'}. I want to convert it to {0.75,0.75,0.75,0.25}. It is basically ratio of counts of level and total observations. My variable has 46 levels. Is there a way to loop it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose I have a series `s`

```
s = pd.Series(list('aaab'))
s

0    a
1    a
2    a
3    b
dtype: object
```

Then use `pd.value_counts` with the `normalize` parameter and map the results

```
s.map(s.value_counts(normalize=True))

0    0.75
1    0.75
2    0.75
3    0.25
dtype: float64
```